# Check if condition is true for a longer time period - not only at a specific time

Tags: jquery

I can't really find the answer to this question. I am sorry if it has already been asked.

Is there a way in jQuery to check if a variable or condition is true for a time period like a second, five seconds or something like that and evoke functions based on the time the variable is true. 
Like function1 if <1 second, function2 if <5 seconds and function 3 if >5 seconds. 
The only way I can imagine a solution is to make a loop and stop it when the variable is false.

EDIT: I am sorry I have asked so unclearly. The question is how to measure the time between one variable being true or false with jQuery.

Comment: I guess the real question is: **Why would you need that?**

Comment: You can't make a condition last for any length of time.  It's either true or false at the moment it's checked.  What you *can* do is re-check at periodic intervals, or write code to respond to events that would change the condition in some way, or use a data-binding framework (think MVVM) to bind your UI to a backing value which would automatically cause the UI to update when that value changes.

Comment: *Is there a way in jQuery or PHP*  Wha?  Those languages reside in different places.  This is a really strange request.

Comment: Imagine a button. This button could be pressed for a specific time to activate there functions

Comment: That "pressed" of the button is an event.  It's not what people think of when you phrase your question with "variable" in the context.  You can capture a mouse down and mouse up for a button press, and calculate the time between.  That's not difficult.

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen: That doesn't really clarify what you're asking.  We can imagine a button.  And we can imagine writing code which would perform some action when the button is clicked.  How is what you're asking different from that?

Comment: I have got at button in real life. The input from that (true/false) is converted to a website which should process this information and do different actions depending on how long time the button is pressed. 
I can use jQuery or PHP it doesn't really matter. Therefore I write both of the languages.

Comment: The time that the button is pressed would be captured on the client side, thus javascript.  Not PHP, which is on the server side.  So in that light, where do you desire to process that time at?  Client or server?  Also, "*I have got at button in real life*"  We want to know what you are actually doing.  I don't know why you would ask otherwise.

Comment: So store the time on `mousedown` and then compare it on `mouseup` - a "click" is just mousedown+mouseup within a pre-defined time - forget about using "click" as you can't press a button then get a click event.

Comment: I would prefer jQuery but I just wanted to inform that PHP was a possibility if needed.

Comment: If you want to process this on the client, then, no, it's not.  Again, PHP runs on the server side.

Comment: @freedomn-m that is the answer I am looking for. So you would use the time when changed as the measure. Thanks

Comment: @Taplar I know. The backend is written in PHP so I thought (if it was needed) I could send the value of the variable to PHP. But it doesn't matter when I don't need PHP.

Comment: Just as a side note, a button can be pressed without using the mouse...

Comment: It is a physical button, tactile button. It is connected to a Raspberry Pi which sends information live to a webserver

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen You should open a new question. Your former question has nothing to do with what you are currently asking in comment?!... You aware there is a big difference between a HTML button, pressed with mouse or keyboard and a physical button set on a RPI?!

Comment: Do physical buttons send the same events?  click / mousedown ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I said nothing about an HTML button in the question. The only thing I said was a condition or variable which the RPI returns to the webpage.'

Comment: @freedomn-m no. The second device (the RPI) sends a variable (true or false) to the website which should process the input

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen You tagged your question with `jQuery` and later talk about a `button`. You ask for us to get some imagination, you get it... Are you able to intercept any event from this physical button? And if so, what are you using as language? I guess it isn't jQuery nor PHP

Comment: @A.Wolff i will gladly open a new question. But I think it is jQuery because the input variable should be processed with jQuery. It was because of my bad English you think there is an HTML button. It is a physical button which returns a variable (true/false).
I am not able to read anything than if the button is pressed or not.

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen You english seems better than mine, only your wording seems bad here. If you open a new question with tag RPI and the OS you are currently using on the RPI, i think you will have more relevant answers. EDIT: seeing your comment to freedomn, i could be completly wrong though

Comment: @A.Wolff you are right that I could use the RPI to register it. I thought it was easier to do on the website (mostly because I already have programmed the RPI to do what it does).

Comment: @RasmusLauridsen Then i think you should fix quickly your issue. It is just a case of intercepting relevant events and using a timer to check time between. GL

Comment: @A.Wolff so you want me to do what? Reformulate my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reword your question to:

> detect how long a variable has been set

then you can use `new Date().getTime()` to get the number of ticks when the value changes and then the same when it changes back (other functions on Date() are available, eg get number of seconds or millseconds).

eg:

```
var t = null;
function start() { t = new Date().getTime(); }
function stop() { t = (new Date().getTime()) - t; }
start();
setTimeout(function() { stop(); }, 1250);
```

you set/reset/check `t` when your condition changes.

You can combine the two start/stop above by checking for `null` to see if it has started, eg:

```
var t = null;
function action() { 
    if (t == null) 
    { 
        t = new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        t = (new Date().getTime()) - t;
        // do something
        onValueChange(t); 
    }
}
action();
setTimeout(function() { action(); }, 1250);
```

---

As an example, in javascript/jquery, using an HTML button, you can record the `mousedown` and compare when you `mouseup` to see how long a button has been pressed, eg:

```js
var t = null;
$("#btn")
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    t = new Date().getTime(); // current ticks
  }).on("mouseup", function() {
    t = new Date().getTime() - t; // delta ticks (could use seconds or milliseconds)

    // Do something with t
    $("#result").text("You pressed for " + t + " ticks.");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn'>press me</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: I understand. That is a great solution I will go with that. I thought the solution a completely other way than this. So thank you